# Display content based on conditional v-if and else on Vue application

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have a product listing in Vue that has product offers. These offers are going to expire when today's date(getting this from an open API: `{{get_date}}`) has crossed the expiry date(defined in the data element `{{product.Expiry_date}}`) of the product.

I am not sure how I can disable some styles and specify new styles of a product offer based on the condition. Let's say I want to hide the buy now button and replace it with "This offer has expired" and I would like to make the contents a bit opaque.

This is what I have:

```
<template>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="nested" v-for="product in products" 
            :key="product.productNumber">

      <div class="valid" v-if=get_date < product.Expiry_date>
        // Show content 
        <div class="one">
          {{product.Name}}
        </div>
        <div class="two">
          {{product.Price}}
        </div>
        <div class="three">
        <button> Buy now</button>
        </div>
     </div>

     <div class= "expired" v-else>
     // I want the button to be hidden and replaced by "This offer has 
        expired" and the other content to be a bit opaque
      <div class="one_expired">
          {{product.Name}}
        </div>
        <div class="two_expired">
          {{product.Price}}
        </div>
        <div class="three_expired">
        This offer has Expired!
        </div>
      </div>

</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted: function() {

    axios
      .get("http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/Berlin", {})
      .then(response => {
        this.date = response.data.datetime;
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  },

  data() {
    return {
      date: "",

      products: [
        {
          ID: 1,
          Name: "Product_1",
          Price: 29,
          Expiry_date: 2019-10-18,
        },
        {
          ID: 2,
          Name: "Product_1",
          Price: 88,
          Expiry_date: 2019-10-12,
        },
      ]
    }
  }
 }
}
</script>

<style scopped>


</style>

// Product 1: Offer is valid
.valid div.one{
   color: blue;     
}
.valid div.two{
  color: blue;          
}

.valid div.three button{
background-color: black;
}


// Product 2: Offer is expired
.expired div.one_expired{
   color: red;    
}
.expired div.two_expired{
  color: red;     
}

.expired{
  opacity: 0.5;  
}

.expired div.three_expired button{
display: none;
}
```

Since I am using more or less the same content for both expired and valid offers, just that the styles are a bit different. Is there a better way to do this? Instead of specifying the styles with different names of classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just specify a conditional class name like:

```html
<div :class="[get_date < product.Expiry_date ? 'valid' : 'expired', 'some-other-class-if-needed']">
  <div class="one">
    {{product.Name}}
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    {{product.Price}}
  </div>
  <div class="three">
    <button v-if="get_date < product.Expiry_date">Buy now</button>
    <div v-else>This offer has Expired!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also instead of using classes `one_expired`, `two_expired` etc for the nested divs you can specify them in the css like:

```css
.expired .one {
  /* style for "one_expired" */
}
.expired .two {
  /* style for "two_expired" */
}
```

Comment: Also, it will be prettier / more readable with the conditional class logic in `computed`. For more info you can check https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Comment: @M3RS yes, agree, though not in this case. because here we are in a `v-for` loop, so no `computed` property is possible. the only way is to call a method.. something like: `isExpired(product.Expiry_date)`.. but then I'm not sure if it is mach prettier or more readable..

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I get a error: `Property or method "valid" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property`. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: oh sorry forgot to add quotes around the class names.. have edited my answer.. should be `... ? 'valid' : 'expired'`